# how to change the style of the bottoms with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not know why the style of the bottoms are not changing.
I tried to save the value and use it to change the color of the bottoms but its not changing. No syntax errors have appeared in the console, so i guess I am okay in that aspect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="main.css">
        <title>testing</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <form>
            <input type="bottom"  class="btn" id="Cgreen" value="click here for green" onclick="changeColor()">
            <input type="bottom"  class="btn" id="Cblue" value="click here for blue"  onclick="changeColor()">
        </form>

        <script>
            var colorg = document.getElementById("Cgreen").value;
            var colorb = document.getElementById("Cblue").value;

            function changeColor() {
                console.log (colorb + colorg);
                if (colorb === "click here for blue") {
                    document.getElementById("Cblue").style = "blue";
                } else if ( colorg === "click here for green") {
                    document.getElementById("Cgreen").style = "green";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by input type "bottom"? Did you mean "button"?

Comment: In a working state, I don't see this logic ever changing the color to green. If  `colorb` is always `"click here for blue"`, the first case will always be true. What is `type="bottom"`? And why not just use an argument?
 `changeColor("green")` for example. And `style` is a collection of style properties, you can't just say "button green"; you need to tell it if you mean text color, background color, border, etc.

Comment: Please check the in id condition you are not swapping the value of the button. Once it's clicked the value too must be changed. If your case it always remains the same. So the color doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues here.

1. **`type="bottom"` is not valid**. Perhaps you mean type `type="button"`?

---

2. **You cannot set an element's `style` to a color directly.**

   You must be more specific. Do you mean background color? Text color? Border color?

   If you're looking to change the color of the background, consider something like this:

   ```
   document.getElementById("Cblue").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   ```

---

3. **Your `if` logic doesn't make sense.**

   It's saying *"If the value of the blue button was "click here for blue" when the page loaded, then the function should change it to blue.*" This will *always* be true, so no matter what you click or what you do, this is the only event that will occur.

   Rather than using conditional logic, just pass the color you want into the function as an argument/parameter. Additionally, if you didn't want to change the element clicked, but instead change a *different* element, you could pass that as a parameter as well.

   Basic example:

```js
function changeColor(elem, color) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="changeColor(this, 'blue');" value="Click for blue">
<input type="button" onclick="changeColor(this, 'green');" value="Click for green">
```

Answer (score 0):

`style` is what "holds the css", if you want to modify a property (let's say `color`) then do `{your stuff here to get the DOM element ...}.style.color = "blue"`

Plus, you never reach the else if block because of it being equivalent to :
`if( !(colorb === "click here for blue") && (colorg === "click here for green") )`. As colorb is **always** equal to "click here for blue" you'll never enter the block.
To fix this, simply end the first `if` statement and let the `else if` become a simple `if` statement :

`if(conditionA){}else if(conditionB){}` will become `if(conditionA){} if(conditionB){}`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `style` here is not the target css property:

```
 document.getElementById("Cgreen").style = "green";
```

With plain JS: for background use

```
 document.getElementById("Cgreen").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

With jQuery: for background use

```
$("#Cgreen").css("background","green");
```

> I do not know why the style of the bottoms are not changing.

On click, your code does not figures out, which html element was clicked.

```js
function changeColor(button) {
  button.style.backgroundColor = button.id.substr(1);
  /* here substr(1) will produce
  Cgreen = green, 
  Cblue = blue 
  */
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn" id="Cgreen" value="click here for green" onclick="changeColor(this)" />
<input type="button" class="btn" id="Cblue" value="click here for blue" onclick="changeColor(this)" />
```

Try this code snippet:

Comment: Just to piggy-back here... as I mentioned in the comments, I don't see a case where the conditional falls into the `else`.

Comment: simply because it can't

Comment: @Santi, as of now, none programming language are capable enough to completely trace out logical errors made by developers(humans).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that means. I was merely saying that you should mention it your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e){
  changeColor($(this));
});

function changeColor(element){
  var colorbutton = element.val();
  if (colorbutton === "click here for blue") {
    $('body').css('backgroundColor','blue');
  }else if (colorbutton === "click here for green"){
    $('body').css('backgroundColor','green');
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="main.css">
    <title>testing</title>

</head>
<body id="body">
<form>
    <input type="button"  class="btn" id="Cgreen" value="click here for green">
    <input type="button"  class="btn" id="Cblue" value="click here for blue">
</form>
</body>
</html>
javascript
```

I don't know will this result be suitable with your purpose ? Hope it solved your problem. I saw you use jquery library, so I rewrite by jquery.